# ext js this argument

Tags: javascript, extjs

In ext-js, what is the difference between doing:

```
this.combo= new Combo(....)
```

and

```
var combo = new Combo().
```

Also...is there a debugger, `System.out.print` kind of functionality in ext js whereby I can see what is the object contained in `'this'` at any moment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Console.log()` in chrome developer's tool or firefox's firebug its equivalent to `System.out.print`

If you're in a function then "var" will create a local variable, else its on the global scope.  As far as `this` it works abit different in javascript than in java. In JavaScript this always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of.  Here is a run through of using `this` in javascript:

[The this keyword in javascript](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)

Comment: voted up. just wanted to add that since this is in context of extjs, knowing Function.createDelegate helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add to the above answer that, it gets trickier when it comes to events as to what `this` refers. By default, `this` refers to the object that fired the event. Meaning that say if you have an AJAX request in an object `o` using `Ajax.request ({...})`, `this` in the `success` event handler by default refers to the Ajax request object not object `o`. But, you can always pass a `scope` parameter while registering your handler function to guarantee what `this` refers in the handler function.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the first question:-
`this.combo` is the current object which fired the event and the var combo is just initialization of a combo box which can be used in the doc. Also, there should be consideration which scope you want while using this.

For the second question:- we can use the debugging options and then the break points to go through what this contains. If you have not put any break point, it by default contains the window object.
[image]